# Is there a definitive list of locales for testing Outlook Add-ins?

Tags: outlook-web-addins

I have a manifest file that has localized URLs and strings for over 20 locales. I have been testing them by changing the language on outlook.live.com, but this is very tedious.

For some languages like French, `Locale="fr"` will work for both French (France) and French (Canada). For other languages like Polish, `Locale="pl"` does not seem to work.

Is there a list or description of which language and region identifiers are supported by Outlook?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a link that has a lot of different localization tips: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/localization

This has a listing of locales:
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc179219(Office.15).aspx

Comment: For languages like French, if I would like to target all French regions (e.g. both France fr-FR and Canada fr-CA), is there a way I can specify that in my manifest file?

Comment: @DanielPhan You didn't read the localization document provided in the answer to your question and ask another question, which has exact answer inside the article as follow: Using just the language name alone, in this case, "fr", is not supported across all combinations of Office host applications and platforms. You better specify separate "fr-fr" and "fr-ca".

Comment: @SlavaIvanov thanks for the pointer. I didn't see it in the article when I first looked.

Comment: Just to confirm then, it looks like there is no way to target `fr-CA`, since it's not on the list in https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc179219(Office.15).aspx, and I can't specify just `fr` -- is that correct? And there is no way to target Spanish for Latin America through the manifest file?